# How to solve $x^n - Ax + A - 1 = 0, n≥4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm currently stuck with this equation, $x^n - Ax + A - 1 = 0$. It has two or three roots depending on the value of n.

One of its roots is always number 1.

I am interested only in the root which is bigger than 1.

Comment: Maybe divide by $x-1$ and see what you end up with?

Comment: mathworker21, I'm looking for an analytical solution for that root. How can I use division by $x-1$ for this?

Comment: @АрсенГоян Because you have spotted that $1$ is a root and hence $(x-1)$ must be a factor.  Dividing by it will given you a lower order polynomial which might be easier to work with.  This is not guaranteed to help but it is worth trying.  I get $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + . . . + 1 = A$.

Comment: What makes you think there is an analytical solution? Most polynomials of high degree can only be solved numerically.

Comment: Because it has some really good-looking solutions, e.g: N=5, A=121, x=3; N=4, A=40, x=3; N=6, A=63, x=2. All those are integer solutions, but can I achieve them with a numerical solution? Anyway, is there a formula to solve it numerically?

Comment: @АрсенГоян Is there a reason for those values of A? Or did you just pick them for the various value of N?

Comment: Actually, that A numbers are the sums of consecutive powers of X up to N. That's how it works

Answer (score 1):

You may just start [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) at a point suitably to the right of $1$, like $x=2\sqrt[n-1]{\frac{A}{n}}-1$, chosen by noticing where the derivative of the given polynomial vanishes.